# Generic Type Information Lost during Serialization/Deserialization with protobuf-net

Tags: protobuf-net, mediatr

I am trying to integrate protobuf-net and mediatR.
The idea is to have a single endpoint where the payload will arrive.
I should then deserialize the Request Message and hand it over to the mediatR which should in turn resolve to the appropriate Handler based on the Request message type.

Every Request inherits from the IRequest.
There is a Result Base Class and lot of Concrete classes that inherit from it.
Like:

```
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(10, typeof(CreateUserRequest))]
[ProtoInclude(11, typeof(DeleteUserRequest))]
[ProtoInclude(12, typeof(GetUserRequest))]
[ProtoInclude(13, typeof(UpdateUserRequest))]
[ProtoInclude(14, typeof(IRequest))]


[ProtoInclude(19, typeof(IRequest<Response>))]
[ProtoInclude(20, typeof(IRequest<CreateUserResponse>))]
[ProtoInclude(21, typeof(IRequest<DeleteUserResponse>))]
[ProtoInclude(22, typeof(IRequest<GetUserResponse>))]
[ProtoInclude(23, typeof(IRequest<UpdateUserResponse>))]
public class Request : IRequest<Response>
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public Guid CorrelationId { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string Requestor { get; set; }
}


 [ProtoContract]
 public class CreateUserRequest : Request, IRequest<CreateUserResponse>
 {
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
 }


 public class CreateUserResponse : Response
 {
     [ProtoMember(1)]
     public string NewUserName { get; set; }
 }
```

The problem is, when I serialize the object with protobuf, the generic information is lost. 
I am doing the deserialization at exactly one place (tried using reflection etc).
I can't deserialize to object of type IRequest.

Is there a way to preserver the information about generic parameters so that I can deserialize my object to be of type IRequest and not just CreateUserRequest ?

And of course, hopefully, what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

The "include" feature is intended to be used with classes, not interfaces. What you are describing is not a supported scenario, because it doesn't offer reliable repeatable deserialization options. Basically, what it is trying to do is allow you to resolve the concrete type; interfaces don't really help you do that - and worse, they make it more confusing since a single type (not mentioned anywhere in your model) could implement **all** of those interfaces - which doesn't really give it much chance.

However, no generic information is lost; by knowing that your type goes down the `CreateUserRequest` path, we already know what interfaces are implemented - they are tied directly into the type definition.

I'm still a little confused about what you're trying to do, but: the code doesn't look at the interfaces when determining a serialization path.